# What are the tools and components needed to work on Silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I see too many downloads in MSDN associated with Silverlight (SDK, toolkit etc).  What do i actually need to develop a data centric LOB application in Silverlight 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Standard or Higher

2.Silverlight 3 Tools

The Silverlight Tools download is pretty much a giant bucket of sorts containing everything you need to get up and running for Silverlight development. You get the developer runtime and various patches and additions to allow you to develop your Silverlight applications in Visual Studio 2008 SP1 or Visual Web Developer Express SP1.

3.Silverlight Toolkit

The Silverlight Toolkit contains a lot of controls developed by Microsoft that don't always ship as a part of Silverlight or the SDK.

4.Deep Zoom Composer

One of the cool features in Silverlight is the ability to visualize large quantities of image data. In order to do this, you will need to prepare your images into the Deep Zoom format, and Deep Zoom Composer allows you to do just that.

Comment: here is the bookmark I copied from:)
http://www.kirupa.com/blend_silverlight/getting_started_silverlight.htm

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 includes a minimum core of tools to do Silverlight 3 development (Silverlight 4 needs more downloads).

For effective development one should consider:

- [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx)
- Libraries and additional controls (to accelerate development), some of these—like [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)—are free.